# Difference between "install" and "installed" in dpkg.log

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, logs, dpkg

Some recently installed packages appear like so:

```
[date] [time] install [package name]
[date] [time] installed [package name]
```

but some packages (e.g. man-db which I haven't manually installed) appear with only:

```
[date] [time] installed [package name]
```

What's the difference?

This observation is from the most recent dpkg log.

Distro: Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela

dpkg version: 1.17.5

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a confusion here between the status lines and the action lines? In any case the log format is described in the `dpkg(1)` man page within the `--log` option description.